# Type of expression is ambiguous for static tuples

Tags: swift

Given the following extension ...

```
extension Double {
    typealias Triple = (Double, Double, Double)
    static let pythagoreanTriple: Triple = (3, 4, 5)
}
```

... why does Swift compiler emits the following errors?

```
// Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
let a: Double = .pythagoreanTriple.0

// Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
func f(_ x: Double) {}
f(.pythagoreanTriple.0)
```

The errors disappear with explicit `Double.pythagoreanTriple.0`.

Why doesn't the compiler infer `Double` in this case?

P.S. This happens only with tuples.

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID394 It doesn't mention how the types are inferred, so I guess you'll have to dig into compiler code to figure this out.

Comment: The compiler does not support this yet. Every chain greater than one will result into this error. If you had `Float.Triple` where `Triple` would be the same as above and `extension Float { static let pythagoreanTriple: Triple = (0, 0, 0) }`. How does the compiler would know which `pythagoreanTriple` to pick for your `f` function? The answer is: it would be ambiguous without more context.

Comment: Just to clarify, this feature is likely to be added into Swift someday, but I don't think it has much priority, so it might take a while. There was some discussion about this on the `swift-evolution` mailing list this year, but I don't have the url.

Comment: @DevAndArtist Thanks for all the insightful comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Slava Pestov](https://twitter.com/slava_pestov) from the *Swift Core Team* at Apple replied on the `swift-users` mailing list:

> My understanding is that `.foo` syntax only works if `foo` is an immediate static member of the contextual type where the expression appears.

Answer (score 0):

You are using static keyword, so to use static variable you have to use the scope name i.e. name of class, struct or extension which is `Double` in your case.

Comment: This is incorrect. The type is indeed inferred if the static member is not a tuple, e.g. struct, enum, etc. Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovič I don't think this is a bug. It's more like by design. But why dd they design this way? You'll have to ask the developers of Swift.

Comment: I asked over at "swift-users" mailing list. Looks like accessing members of an inferred type like I do here is not supported _yet_.